# Ruby on Rails: only display category on index page if it contains any articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create an index page showing all categories **in alphabetical order**, but only if an article has been tagged to that category. An article can have many categories.

When index page is first loaded, it will only show 2 categories. There is a "load more" ajax button at the bottom of the index page to load the next 2 categories.

I think there is an error with how i am assigning the categories variable. The ajax button works, but the same 2 category names are being shown (eg. "A" and "B", instead of the next 2 (eg "C" & "D").

**Categories controller**

```
  def index
    if params[:name]
      @categories = Category.with_articles.order('name ASC').where('name> ?', params[:name]).limit(2)
    else
      @categories = Category.with_articles.order('name ASC').limit(2)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**category/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @categories %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "article_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "article_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
  end
```

**models/category.rb**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :articles, through: :article_categories

  def self.with_articles
    includes(:articles).where.not(articles: { id: nil })
  end

end
```

**EDIT:**
**models/article_category.rb**

```
class ArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :article
belongs_to :category

end
```

**models/article.rb**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
end**
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.articles.order('name ASC').limit(2)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

I think this will resolve and you can remove from model `category` the function `with_articles`.

Comment: I can't associate articles with category like this: "Category.articles", because i am using a has-many through association for the category model. Instead, i use "Category.includes(:articles), but the same issue occurs.

Comment: try : `Category.joins(:articles)`

Comment: Can you post the issue that appears?

Comment: Changing it to joins now stops the ajax button from working, and the same category name is repeated twice. I have added a screenshot. Basically, i have 5 categories, eg "A" and "B" shows on page initial load, when i click load more, "C" and D" should show, but currently "A" and "B" gets repeated again and again each time the load more button appears.

Comment: Okay, I have an idea. Can you tell me how you're calling in your view? And I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think that this limit (2) will always bring the first two records. Then you could use kaminari to leave only the first two records. Return the category index to normal. So, `@categories = Category.all` .

In the view when you are going to call the union of the two, do `@category.articles` and the kaminari will limit on the page.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `offset` thing. You need to maintain a `param` say `offset` and send it every ajax request
Offset lets you get the `n - the number of records` as passed in limit function after skipping - the number of records`passed in`offset` function.

So, Ideally After fetching first two records from Database you need to get other two records by skipping first two records so you need to pass `offset` as 2 in your params

```
def index
  if params[:name]
    @categories = Category.with_articles.order(:name).where('name> ?', params[:name]).limit(2).offset(params[:offset].to_i)
  else
    @categories = Category.with_articles.order(:name).limit(2).offset(params[:offset].to_i)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This did not work for me.. the same 2 category names keep on rendering and adds on below the existing categories each time i click the load more button.

Comment: Did you used `offset` and sent it as a param ?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code above to my controller

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but it seems to be like you are making it more complex.

```
def index
  @categories = Category.articles.where('articles.id > ?',params[:id]).order('name ASC').limit(2)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

In Ajax call you can send the `id` of the last article. Hope it works!